# Automating NFSv3 File/Folder permissions in Windows

Tags: windows, nfs, file-permissions, access-control-list

I'm a Windows/MSSQL DBA who is inheriting a quirky system through no fault of my own, and had a quick question.

**Background**

I have an Azure NFSv3 volume that is being exported to a Windows Server 2019 VM for the purposes of copying data in bulk from an existing Windows ecosystem. The issue that I'm running into is that ACLs are not inherited in NFSv3 (AFAIK) and so every file and folder I copy to the NFS volume gets its own ACL, and I don't seem to be able to set a default. The current count is 943,318 files and folders, so manually editing the ACLs via *Properties->NFS Attributes->File permissions (mode)* is not a viable option.

**Question**

So my question is - Is there a way to set NFS ACLs in bulk via PowerShell, Windows Command shell or even a COTS product? I suspect the answer is no, in which case I'll have to see about getting a Linux machine and exporting the NFS volume to that. At this point-in-time we're a 99.9% Windows-based enterprise, so it's non-trivial to stand up a Linux VM, but it can be done.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Can you upgrade to NFSv4? It should support windows ACLs.

Comment: @wazoox - It's certainly theoretically possible, but NFSv4 has caused interoperability problems in other parts of the solution. It ultimately comes down to whether this or that is the bigger problem. :/

Comment: The problem is that NFSv3 is definitely a poor fit for Windows. SMB or NFSv4 are better. Do you have WSL on your windows 2019 VM?